# Zoho creator ,Invalid JSON payload received, when trying to integrate creator-form-data to google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, zoho

Objective: I am trying to integrate creator-form-data with google-sheet using google-sheet-api-v4.

I am able to create an empty sheet(data params being empty ) at google spreadsheets.
but i don't know ,how to create sheet with data-params , to either-

(1) assign title ,to spreadsheet , or
(2) write any data, to spreadsheet

error received : using deluge to perform task no. ( 1 ), the error thrown is :

Invalid JSON payload received. Unexpected token

Note:
(1)Oauth credentials are checked and correct,
  google access token is also valid, confirming via 
[Google-oauth-playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/)

(2) i am able to assign title and data from google-try-api-platform,but no success from deluge side.
[google-sheet-try-api](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/create?apix=true)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The issue is solved now ,in postUrl the  post-data to be posted , must be converted from json to string (params=data.toString(); ).
I had sent post-data in json format thats the mistake I made.

Below is correct sample code for deluge:

```
 append_data = {"values":{{thisDate,thisQuantity}}};
 final_append_data = append_data.toString();

 response = postUrl(append_data_sheet_url,final_append_data,mymap,false);
```

Note: variable "final_append_data" is converted to string.